# how to use Arrays.toString directly in java (without Arrays. before it)

Tags: java, arrays, tostring, fill, println

Imagine I make an array e.g. `int[] a = new int[5]`, why I cannot use `System.out.print(toString(a))`? I imported the method by the way, `import static java.util.Arrays.toString;`
but I get compile error
I'm assuming I'm using a wrong import
for example I had no issue with Arrays.fill and I can use fill directly , e.g. fill(a,10) works perfectly fine but toString(a) will have compile error

Comment: "I get compile error": what specific error are you getting?

Comment: I suppose because Object#toString takes precedence?

Comment: It probably gets confused by the `toString` method of your own class, inherited from `Object`. In any case, you should not develop a habit of statically importing such methods. It makes your code less readable (though it's considered OK in specific cases such as Math functions where you have complex expressions).

Comment: Yes. Since `toString` is always available in the same class as you're writing the code, using `toString` will always refer to the current class' `toString` method rather than the one imported from `Arrays`. And since `toString` accepts no arguments, the compiler complains.

Comment: It's not so much 'confused' - the spec clearly outlines that any presence of a statically imported name in local context, regardless of param counts, means the static import is to be entirely disregarded. Javac does as one expects: It follows the spec to the letter.

Comment: Your only way to hack this around is to define a `toString(in[])` method in your current class and delegate to `Arrays.toString(int[])`. But you shouldn't.

Comment: error is : non-static method toString() cannot be referenced from a static context

Answer (score 4):

What you want is **impossible**.

The problem is specifically that all classes inherently extend from `Object`; you can't opt out of that (even if you write no `extends` clause at all, such as `class Foo {}`, then `javac` compiles this as if you wrote `class Foo extends Object{}`; you can't tell javac not to do this).

And `java.lang.Object` defines the method: `public String toString() { ...}`. Which means your class, like every class in all of java, has a method named `toString()`. You can't tell javac to un-define a method. It's there. Whether you write it or not.

And static imports are defined as simply not existing if their name clashes with a name your class already has, *even if* the parameter list cannot match up (the various `Arrays.toString` method all take at least 1 param, the toString() your own class has, takes zero).

Hence, what you want, is impossible. It's an artefact of the choice of name: Had that `Arrays.toString()` method been named anything else, you could have used a static import.

### Solution 1 - stop using arrays

The primary solution is *to stop using arrays* - they are low level constructs that should be used only by libraries that offer high level features (i.e. that write the high level features, based on low level features). An example: `java.util.ArrayList` internally uses an array - that's appropriate use of arrays.

This advice definitely counts very very strongly when you make arrays of non-primitive types (i.e. any java code that uses `String[]` anywhere is suspect. There are loads of downsides, and effectively zero upsides, to `String[]` in contrast to a `List<String>`). Less so when we're talking about arrays of primitive types, such as `int[]` (there are quite a few good reasons to use an `int[]` instead of a `List<Integer>`).

Lists don't need these kludges. Their `toString()` is fine. Their `hashCode()` and `equals()` implementations are fine. They can grow and shrink.

### Solution 2 - bridgers

You can of course do the work here. You can for example make this:

```
public class ArrayTools {
  public static String arrToString(int[] a) {
    return Arrays.toString(a);
  }
}
```

and then use it:

```
import static com.foo.hashemi.ArrayTools.*;

void example() {
  int[] x = {1, 2};
  System.out.println(arrToString(x));
}
```

### Solution 3 - lombok extensionmethod

Add lombok to your project, then:

```
class ArrayTools {
  public static String arrToString(int[] a) {
    return Arrays.toString(a);
  }
}

// and to use

@ExtensionMethod(ArrayTools.class)
class Example {
  void foo() {
    int[] x = {1, 2};
    System.out.println(x.arrToString());
  }
}
```

For the same reason the static import of `Arrays.toString()` doesn't work, you can't extension-method `Arrays.toString` onto `int[]` and friends - because it clashes with the existing (useless) `toString()` all objects (and arrays are objects) have.

### Solution 4 - set up your tools to make this less annoying

`Arrays.toString()` isn't that big a deal. Most IDEs can be told to default-include all methods in a certain class in auto-complete dialogs (i.e. assume they are imported by default). For example in eclipse, open your preferences, then navigate to:

Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Favorites

And add `java.util.Arrays.toString` to the list. Now you can simply type `toStr` anywhere, hit CTRL+SPACE (or whatever keyboard shortcut you set up for autocomplete) and `Arrays.toString` will be in the list.